# dynamic delay configuration in spring poller

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

Polling dynamically

I am using poller component from integration to poll files from s3.The fixed delay is 15 min and  max message rate is 1 .The reason i did this was in down stream messages  in xd were clogging  since I am using http.Now this is file for 100k records file but when file size is small i still wait 15 min though i can process fast.Now is there any way to dynamically set delay depending in size of file.Because we don't know which files will be polled also to know  it?Depending on file size i will pick up or number of records can we change dynamically the fixed delay or fixed rate?

```
<int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true" max-messages-per-poll="${maxMessageRate}">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>


<bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
    <constructor-arg ref="healthCheckStrategy"/>

</bean>

<bean id="healthCheckStrategy" class="test.ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy">
    <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="doHealthCheck" value="${doHealthCheck}"/>
</bean>



<bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
    <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
    <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
</bean>



<bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
    <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
    <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/>
</bean>


<bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
    <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
    <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
    <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
</bean>



<!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                    bucket="${bucket}"
                                    s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                    credentials-ref="credentials"
                                    file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                    remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                    channel="splitChannel"
                                    local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                    accept-sub-folders="false"
                                    delete-source-files="true"
                                    archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                    archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
</int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:splitter id="s3splitter" input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="bridge" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

    <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
        </bean>
    </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

</int-file:splitter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Spring Integration 4.2 the `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` has been [introduced](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers):

> This method is called after the receive() method; again, you can reconfigure the source, or take any action perhaps depending on the result (which can be null if there was no message created by the source). You can even return a different message!

Starting with version 4.3 we introduce `CompoundTriggerAdvice`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#_compoundtriggeradvice

Which you can use for your use-case based on the `payload` size.

Comment: Suppose there are  3 files a.file  100 mb  b.file 1 mb and c.file 10 mb .I think poller will  pull it randomly ?I want a.file have fixed delay of 10 min file b 1 min and file c 5 min

Comment: M-m-m. It doesn't matter. You want to change the next poll time on the current message. That everything you can do in the `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice.afterReceive()` impl and use `DynamicPeriodicTrigger` to change its `period` based on the file size.

Comment: Thanks will try that